# Problem reading file with pandas uploaded to a django view

Tags: django, pandas, django-rest-framework

I'm uploading some excel and csv files to a django view using axios, then i pass those files to a function that uses pandas read_csv and read_excel functions to process them, the first problem i had was with some excel files that had some non utf-8 characters that pandas was unable to read, the only solution i found was to set "engine = 'python'" when reading the file (changing the encoding to utf-8-sig or utf-16 didn't work).

This works when i'm testing the script from my terminal, but when i use the same script on a view i get the following error: ValueError("The 'python' engine cannot iterate through this file buffer.")

This is the code i'm using:

```
try:
  data = pandas.read_csv(request.FILES['file'], engine="python")
except:
  print("Oops!",sys.exc_info(),"occured.")
```

trying the same function through the terminal works fine

```
pandas.read_csv("file.csv", engine="python")
```

Comment: If the file is the same in both instances it suggests there could be an issue either passing or selecting the file to the request object, if you print the files dict to console before reading the csv what do you get?

Comment: The name of the file: file.csv
And if i print the type: <class 'django.core.files.uploadedfile.InMemoryUploadedFile'>
Is there a way to transform this type of file to the normal python file type?

Comment: pandas.read_csv(request.FILES['file']) should work without needing to convert the uploaded file class to another file like object, have you tried without specifying the engine?

Comment: yeah, it works just fine without setting the engine (i think it uses "c" by default) but then i can't read some files with strange characters